# Indesign: Align frames on same position but different pages

Tags: adobe-indesign

This might be an idiotic question and I'll take my chances. I'm an amateur Indesigner (but am a power user). I would like to align a frame on a different page on a different spread (could even be on the same spread, just on the flip-side page of it).

But my ruler shows 58p something for the left hand side of one frame, and 11p something on the other side (please see screenshot attached for reference). How can I position the leftmost frame in the same position relative to the page, as the rightmost frame of reference? (besides using a calculator, I want the simple option)

[image: screenshot of what i want to do]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click, hold, and drag the ruler origin (top left corner where they meet) to move the 0s.

You can place the ruler at the center of the spread and measure from there.